# Demonstration of Rank condition in Simultaneous equations

Tags: model, structural-equation-modeling

I have searched throughout the Internet trying to find a demonstration of the RANK condition to Simultaneous Equation Model (SEM) but I couldn't find it.

For Equation Systems with well defined system of equations (endogenous in left side and exogenous in right side) I already have seen the proof of Rank Conditions. But, for econometrics, when we are studying SEM, the  system has both exogenous and edogenous (or dependent and independent) variables all in same "matrix".

In this models, Rank condition define that I should exclude the column that values are not null in line (equation) that I'm interested to know if it has a solution and try to find a Det =/= 0 in submatrix.

Such "rule" appears in every econometrics book, but none shows the proof.

Can someone Help me to understand where condition came from?

Comment: I thought [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) came from linear algebra, which can affect the identifiability of some models. Is that not what you are referring to by "rank condition"?

Comment: SEM is usually structural equation modeling.